# Repassar dados capturados de um código Python para Shell Script

Tags: python, shell-script, raspberry-pi

Gostaria de saber o que fazer para pegar esses dados captados de um sensor DHT11 (Código em Python [Temperatura e Umidade]) e passá-los para um script em Shell

```
if umid is not None and temp is not None:
     print("Temperatura = {0:0.1f}Umidade{1:0.1f}\n").format(temp,umid);
```

Comment: Você quer passá-los um por vez, ou múltiplos por vez?

Answer (score 2):

Faça assim:

```
from subprocess import call

call(["sh", "caminho_do_script.sh",  temp, umid])
```

Você precisará usar um `list`. O primeiro item desse list é o comando, e o restante, os argumentos.

No exemplo acima, é como se eu tivesse chamando direto do Bash (supondo os valores de `temp` e `umid`):

```
sh caminho_do_script.sh 30.6 10.2
```

Existem várias formas de fazer isso em Python, como por exemplo usando `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system("sh caminho_do_script.sh {0:0.1f} {1:0.1f}".format(temp,umid))
```

Se quiser mais opções, pode dar uma olhada nessa resposta do [Stackoverflow  English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)